# Como contar as linhas de uma saída no terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Quero contar o total de saídas dos resultados no terminal.

Por exemplo usando o `cat lista_de_compras.txt`:

```
arroz
feijão
leite
```

Quero receber **3**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use o grep:

`grep -c ^ lista_de_compras.txt`

A saída será 3

---

ou user o cat com o `wc`

`cat lista_de_compras.txt |wc -l`

A saída será 3

---

Ou Use apenas o `wc`:

`wc -l lista_de_compras.txt`

A saída será 3

---

Comment: obrigado, ajudou muito